Finding the most similar vector given data points
I work in the jewelry industry and I would like to build a price quote estimator for my sales team. The price of an engagement ring setting can be pretty well approximated if you know the gold weight, the number of diamonds on the setting, the size of those diamonds, etc. I would like feed some function a bunch of parameters and it would return a quote. The quote would come from a large data sheet where each entry has some number of parameters from previous designs and an associated quote.
My degree is in math and I recall doing exercises where you compare vectors against each other and get a value which would indicate how similar those vectors are. I'm almost positive I can apply this to solve my problem. It's been a while so the specifics are blurred in my mind. Norms come to mind? I figured asking here might streamline my research.
Secondly, what is the best way to put this into practice? Would Google Sheets work or is it easier to write up some python code?
I don't need the full blown answer to this problem, just the main tools to brush up on in order to get this done.
Look forward to some help.

You might be thinking of the norm of the difference between the two vectors, which corresponds to the distance between the points they represent if you treat them as position vectors. There are different norms, though, so you may want to think about which one is most appropriate. Perhaps if you share a bit more about the type of calculation you're looking at (maybe add a simple example to your question) it'll be easier to help.

Yes, I remember there being more than one norm. I looked those up and I think the one you're referring to might be helpful. In the most basic form I'm trying to do this -
Given a data point with following components [metal wight, carat total weight, size per diamond]. For example [2.34, .40, .05]. Then we would compare that against a bunch of other data points. for example [2.00, .10, .02], [2.36, .35, .03],...
In this case the second data point would be the closest match. We would get the price for that and then that would be best estimated price for the data we provided.

One thing you'll want to be careful about is units, and how they affect the relative importance (weighting) of each component. For example, if you switched from (say) grammes to milligrammes for the first component, your vectors would become $[2000,0.4,0.05]$ and $[2360,0.35,0.03]$ and the relative importance of the first component would be far greater. (Hopefully you can see what I mean, obviously I don't know which actual units you're using.) With that in mind, you might want to deliberately incorporate weighting into your calculation.

That makes sense, thank you. This gave me a good starting point. I realized I can query chatGPT a little bit too, I forget that's an option. I'll probably post again here with solution to a get a second opinion. Appreciate the help so far. Pretty cool to put this stuff into action!
